# MongoDB $lookup with <collection to join> coming from the input document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

New to mongodb, so maybe this is a dumb question. I am using MongoDB lookup aggregation, but the 'from' collection is a field in the input document. How do I indicate that field in the 'from' rather than a string literal?

A simplified version of the collection I am starting with ("Groups") has documents that look like this:

```
{
   _id: "<ObjectId>",
   collectionName: "MyCollectionA",
   list: ["<Foreign ObjectId>", "<Foreign ObjectId>", "<Foreign ObjectId>"]
}
```

I am joining to another collection. In this case, "MyCollectionA".

My lookup is working and looks like this:

```
{ 
   $lookup: {
      from: "MyCollectionA",  
      localField: "list",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "myJoinedItems"    
   }
}
```

However, I want to be able to use the field 'collectionName' rather than hardcoding 'MyCollectionA' in the lookup. How can I do that? I've tried '$collectionName' and { $literal: '$collectionName }, but no luck.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to pass collection name dynamically in FROM !!

Comment: Agreee with above; not possible in a single agg pipeline.   But can be done with 2 aggs with the second in a loop.   Question:  Is `collectionName` in the `Groups` collection unique across all docs?   Or could several docs have the same value for `collectionName`, and then if so, is the list of objectIds in `list` across that set of docs?

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti - In Groups collection, collectionName can be repeated across documents. However, within a Groups document, there is one collectionName and all of the ids in list will relate to that one collection.

Answer (score 0):

The following query can do the trick. We are iterating over each record of `Groups` collection and performing the find operation on the collection specified in each document for the list of object IDs. Since there is a default index on _id, the search operation would be fast.

```
db.Groups.find().forEach(doc=>{
    var myJoinedItems = [];
    doc["list"].forEach(id=>{
        myJoinedItems.push(
            db.getCollection(doc["collectionName"]).find({"_id":id})[0]
        );
    });
    doc["myJoinedItems"]=myJoinedItems;
    print(tojson(doc));
});
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d6cac366bc2ad3b23f7de74"),
    "collectionName" : "MyCollectionA",
    "list" : [
        ObjectId("5d6cabd16bc2ad3b23f7de72")
    ],
    "myJoinedItems" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d6cabd16bc2ad3b23f7de72"),
            "collectionDetails" : {
                "name" : "MyCollectionA",
                "info" : "Cool"
            }
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d6cb82a6bc2ad3b23f7de76"),
    "collectionName" : "MyCollectionB",
    "list" : [
        ObjectId("5d6cb7fd6bc2ad3b23f7de75")
    ],
    "myJoinedItems" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d6cb7fd6bc2ad3b23f7de75"),
            "collectionDetails" : {
                "name" : "MyCollectionB",
                "info" : "Super-Cool"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

## **Data set:**

**Collection:** Groups

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d6cac366bc2ad3b23f7de74"),
    "collectionName" : "MyCollectionA",
    "list" : [
        ObjectId("5d6cabd16bc2ad3b23f7de72")
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d6cb82a6bc2ad3b23f7de76"),
    "collectionName" : "MyCollectionB",
    "list" : [
        ObjectId("5d6cb7fd6bc2ad3b23f7de75")
    ]
}
```

**Collection:** MyCollectionA

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d6cabd16bc2ad3b23f7de72"),
    "collectionDetails":{
        "name":"MyCollectionA",
        "info":"Cool"
    }
}
```

**Collection:** MyCollectionB

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d6cb7fd6bc2ad3b23f7de75"),
    "collectionDetails":{
        "name":"MyCollectionB",
        "info":"Super-Cool"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a variation that uses `$lookup` directly.

```
db.foo.drop();
db.foo1.drop();
db.foo2.drop();

db.foo.insert(
[
 {_id:0, collectionName:"foo1", list: ['A','B','C'] },
 {_id:1, collectionName:"foo2", list: ['D','E'] }
]);

db.foo1.insert([
{_id:0, key:"A", foo1data:"goodbye"},
{_id:1, key:"B", foo1data:"goodbye"},
{_id:2, key:"C", foo1data:"goodbye"}
]);

db.foo2.insert([
{_id:0, key:"C", foo2data:"goodbye"},
{_id:1, key:"D", foo2data:"goodbye"}
]);

// Pass 1:  Collect unique collections.                                         
c = db.foo.distinct("collectionName");

// Pass 2:  Get 'em:                                                            
c.forEach(function(collname) {
        c2 = db.foo.aggregate([
        {$match: {"collectionName": collname}}
        ,{$lookup: {"from": collname,
                     // Clever twist: if localField is a list, then the lookup
                     // behaves like an in-list:
                     localField: "list", 
                     foreignField: "key",
                     as: "X" }}

         ]);

    });
```